# BeautifulSoup freeze when using 'class'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is my html `source code`

```
<h1 class="companyName__9bd88132">Chipotle Mexican Grill Inc</h1>
<div class="description__ce057c5c">Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.</div>
```

I want to get only the description: Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.

Input:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", {"class" : "description"})
```

**Output:** script hangs

Input:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
for n in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "description"}):
    print(n)
```

**Output:** Script hangs

Input:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
for n in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "description"}):
    print(n)
```

**Output**: `None`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{"class" : "description"}` will only find tags with class that's *exactly* equal to `description`. Your class is only begins with `description__...`.

You can use CSS selector `div[class^="description"]` to select the required element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source_code = '''
<h1 class="companyName__9bd88132">Chipotle Mexican Grill Inc</h1>
<div class="description__ce057c5c">Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('div[class^="description"]').text)
```

Prints:

```
Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.
```

---

Or you can use `.find()` with lambda:

```
print(soup.find(class_=lambda t: t.startswith('description')).text)
```

Comment: this is so helpful

Answer (score 2):

you said your html looks like this

```
<h1 class="companyName__9bd88132">Chipotle Mexican Grill Inc</h1>
<div class="description__ce057c5c">Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.</div>
```

and this is the python which you will use to **scrape** that html's text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'html.parser') # or you ca use lxml if you want to
for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "description"}): # or attrs{'class': 'description'} 
    print(i.text)
```

and you will get an output which is like this

```
Chipotle Mexican Grill Inc
Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. owns and operates quick serve Mexican restaurants. The Company manages restaurants throughout the United States.
```